# How can I get Appearance properties vlaues of my custom web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I am developing a web part, I created a custome properties and controls. but I need to read the width value in the Appearance group of the web part. how I can access to these values in codebehind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the WebPart class you can just use its [Width Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.width%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

`Unit width = this.Width;`